# Setting the right amount of bars in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get my page to display some lines that are centered vertically and would like for them to take up the whole width of the page, but the problem is that the page screws up if the page has extra lines if the page is minimized. How can I fix that since it is too hard to detect the right amount of lines to put for every screen height?

Expected behavior:

```
|-------------------------|
|                         |
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|                         |
|-------------------------|
```

Behavior that I get:

```
|-------------------------|
|                         |
| |||||||||||||||||||||||||
| |||||||||               |
|-------------------------|
```

My Code:

```
<style>
body{
    background-color: #b5ff8e;
}


hr{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 40px;
}

.bars {
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>        


<div class="bars">

<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god why the hell are you doing this

Comment: Why? Use a repeating background image or [repeating linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this using css only:

The main goal is to prevent the container  to wrap determined by the content ( hr elements).

To achieve this, the height needs to be specified, same height as the hr elements and overflow: hidden to clip the content.

```
body{
    background-color: #b5ff8e;
}


hr{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 40px;
}

.bars {
    height: 500px; // same as hr height
    overflow: hidden; // clip content
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/WzdRpj

Comment: This is perfect! Just one thing, would you know how to fix it so that it falls that gap at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Set the width by %'s instead of set pixels. So youd probably want something like 2%. Use javascript to increment it. But why.